# HTML radio buttons will not display side by side

Tags: html, css, forms, button, input

I'm having some trouble with my HTML form, I've tried looking it up and looking for solutions online and the "solutions" I found did not work for me. The issue that I am having is that my Radio Buttons are not displaying side-by-side. And i believe I know why, but if i get of what's causing it, it mucks up the rest of my form.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>

    <title>Survey</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="P9Style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <h1 align="Center">
        SURVEY
    </h1>
</body>

<form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php">

    <br>

    <label for="myName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="myName" id="Name">

    <label for="myEmail">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="myEmail" id="Email">

    <br><br>

    <label for="Favorite_Browser">Favorite Browser:</label>
    <select size="1" name="Favorite_Browser" id="Favorite Browser">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
        <option value="Mozzila Firefox">Mozzila Firefox</option>
        <option value="Apple Safari">Apple Safari</option>
        <option value="Opera Browser">Opera Browser</option>
    </select>


    <br><br>


    Select your favorite Programming Language:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fav_Lang" id="fav_Lang" value="VB.net">VB.Net
    <input type="radio" name="fav_Lang" id="fav_Lang" value="Java">Java
    <input type="radio" name="fav_Lang" id="fav_Lang" value="HTML">HTML
    <input type="radio" name="fav_Lang" id="fav_Lang" value="C++">C++
    <input type="radio" name="fav_Lang" id="fav_Lang" value="Ruby">Ruby

    <br><br>

    <label for="myComments">Comments:</label>
    <textarea name="myComments" id="Comments:" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>



    <input id ="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
</form>

<!-- Footer space-->
<div id="footer">
    <br>
    Copyright &copy; 2013 Richard Paulicelli
    <br>
    You can send me an email at <a href="mailto:richardpaulicelli@yahoo.com">richardpaulicelli@yahoo.com</a>
    <br><br>
</div>
<!-- End Footer space-->
```

Here is my CSS style sheet code:

```
form { background-color: #eaeaea;
       font-family: Arial, sans-erif;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10; }

label { float: left;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px; }

input, textarea, select { margin-top: 10px; display: block; }


#mySubmit { margin-left: 110px; }

#footer { background-color: #CCCFFF;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333; 
    font-size: 1em; 
    clear: both; }
```

Now what I believe is causing the problem is in my CSS style sheet and it's this line right here:

```
    input, textarea, select { margin-top: 10px; display: block; }
```

However, if I remove `input` it fixes the radio buttons but the rest of my form is messed up.

I have tried doing `input.radio { display: inline; }`

I have tried doing `#fav_Lang input.radio { display: inline; }` (fav_Lang being the radio buttons name and ID).

So i'm at a total loss on what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't have more than one ID name on a page. It's supposed to be identification. They should all have different ID values.

Comment: Yea, it wasn't like that before, It was all different, but I changed it to the same one to try different things. I've changed it back already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector should be `input[type=radio]`

[Demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/iteWiju/1/edit)

Keep in mind that it's best practice avoid applying styles that need to be overridden later. Check out [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) and [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do

```
input.radio { display: inline; }
```

then you need to add `class="radio"` to your radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted way long ago, but I found this thread because I was looking for the same thing. I'm also a novice learner/new here, so please critique me if I'm contributing to a discussion in a wrong way. Apologies and thanks in advance.
Anyway...

I found a project where the guy used only html to do this thing you're asking about.

I'll try to give an example:

```
<div>
    <label>Is this what you're trying to do?</label>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio">Cool Radio Button</td>
        <td><input type="radio">Not Cool</td>
        <td><input type="radio">Totally Missed The Point</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

[This](https://codepen.io/allare/pen/GzvvYL) is his codepen.

Comment: Hi!, the example may work, but consider that <tr> should always be inside a <table> element